# Excel - How to calculate the sum of a different column values based on the conditional values of another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the PAR values, whose formula is:

PAR-3 = Total Outstanding Values (for 0-3 overdue days) / Gross outstanding balance
      = (43,100 + 1,08,000)/ 11,54,700
      = 0.130

Similarly I shall calculate for PAR-7, PAR-15, PAR-30 etc

Now for the attached excel sheet, for calculating PAR-3, I need the sum of Outstanding amount values for the given range of overdue days. Only if the range of "Days Overdue" is between 0-3, then only select the corresponding cell of "Outstanding Amount" and finally sum it up.

I tried looking for solutions using VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, Pivot Tables etc, but in vain.

[image: My Excel Sheet]

Answer (score 0):

Use [`SUMIF()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b) and [`SUMIFS()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) formulas.

0-3 days:

```
=SUMIF(F2:F29;"<4",O2:O29)
```

4-7 days:

```
=SUMIFS(O2:O29;F2:F29,">3",F2:F29,"<8")
```

8-15 days:

```
=SUMIFS(O2:O29;F2:F29,">7",F2:F29,"<16")
```

16-30 days:

```
=SUMIFS(O2:O29;F2:F29,">15",F2:F29,"<31")
```

30+ days:

```
=SUMIF(F2:F29;">30",O2:O29)
```